# Symfony FOSRestController Empty Response

Tags: php, symfony, http-status-codes

I have put method and I want after logic have some response "Projects successful update" and I use statusCodes when number error and description but I have 204 No Content, when my action done. But when

```
return "update old project";
```

but this is wrong I want use status code with description, why I have not response not understand

```
Response Body [Raw]

"update old project"
```

my action

```
    /**
 * Update existing Projects from the submitted data or create a new Projects at a specific location.
 * @Put("/projects/{slug}", name="put", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 * @ApiDoc(
 * resource = true,
 * description = "Create/Update single Projects",
 *  parameters={
 *      {"name"="level", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="project choice - Senior, Middle+, Middle, Middle/Junior, Junior"},
 *      {"name"="main_skill", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="mainskill project"},
 *      {"name"="name", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="additional information"},
 *      {"name"="duration", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="1 year+, 3 months+, 2 weeks"},
 *      {"name"="location", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="location project"},
 *      {"name"="expected_budget", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="expected_budget project"},
 *      {"name"="start_date", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="start date project"},
 *      {"name"="description", "dataType"="string", "required"=false, "description"="description"},
 *      {"name"="employment", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="employment"},
 *      {"name"="project_skills", "dataType"="array", "required"=true, "description"="project skills project"},
 *      {"name"="markets", "dataType"="array", "required"=true, "description"="project markets "},
 *      {"name"="platforms", "dataType"="array", "required"=true, "description"="project platforms "},
 *      {"name"="token", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="is equally md5('email'.secret_word)"},
 *      {"name"="speciality", "dataType"="array", "required"=true, "description"="project speciality"},
 *      {"name"="type", "dataType"="string", "required"=false, "description"="project type - fixed_cost or time_and_material"},
 *      {"name"="rate", "dataType"="integer", "required"=true, "description"="project rate"}
 *
 *  },
 * statusCodes = {
 * 200 = "Projects successful update",
 * 404 = "Return when project with current slug not isset",
 * 101 = "Secret token is not valid"
 * },
 *  section="Project"
 * )
 * @RestView()
 *
 * @param  Request $request
 * @param  string $slug
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function putProjectAction(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $token = $this->get('request')->request->get('token');
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Users')->findOneBySecuritytoken($token);
    $projectOld = $manager->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Project')
        ->putProjectClient($slug, $user);
    $data = $request->request->all();
    $view = View::create();
    if(empty($projectOld)){
        $view->setData('not find user project');
    }
    if(empty($user)){
        $view->setData('not find user');
    }
    if (!empty($user)) {
        $data = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($data, 'json');

        $projectOld = $manager->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Project')
            ->findOneBySlug($slug);
        $projectNew = $this->get('serializer')
            ->deserialize($data, 'Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Project', 'json');
        if (!$projectOld) {
            $projectNew->setUserId($user);
            $projectNew->setCurrentStatus('not_approved');
            $projectNew->setStrippedName();
            $manager->persist($projectNew);
            $manager->flush();
            $view->setStatusCode(404);
        } else {
            $this->get('artel.project.update')->updateObject($projectOld, $projectNew);
            $manager->flush();
            $view->setStatusCode(200);
        }
    }else{
        $view->setStatusCode(101);
    }
    return $view;
}
```

I test it with sanbox because postman not sent parameters in request if I test PUT method, with POST sent parameters to action.

Answer (score 0):

is this an API? 
If it is the case , ¿why dont you use the Response object? 
You can set the response code and if you like use the Serializer to give a format such as xml or json.

In the [fundamentals](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html#step-2-the-server-returns-a-response) you can find what im saying

For example:

> return new Response($this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($access, 'json'),200, array("Content-Type" => "application/json;charset=utf-8"));

This will return a response in json format , code 200 , and content type "application/json"

Hope it helps